# Getting a single array containing div class names and their inner li class names using php dom xpath query

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Could someone please help me with this, the supposed answers I have received for a similar question doesn't really answer it.  I have 2 xpath queries for a html source, 1 which returns an array of div class names that contains "top-menu" within its name, and another that returns an array of inner li class names (of those div class names that contains "top-menu").  Is there an elegant way to combine the 2 so that only a single array is returned in the following format?

```
Array
(
[0] => top-menu top-menu-2
   (
    [0] => menu-item top-menu-item top-menu-item-1
    [1] => menu-item top-menu-item top-menu-item-2
   )
[1] => top-menu top-menu-8
  (
    [0] => menu-item x
  )
 )
```

Html source:

```
  <div class="top-menu top-menu-2">
  <ul class="j-menu">
          <li class="menu-item top-menu-item top-menu-item-1">               
    </li>
          <li class="menu-item top-menu-item top-menu-item-2">
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="top-menu top-menu-8">
 <ul class="j-menu">
          <li class="menu-item x">               
          </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Code to return array of inner li class names of parent div class (which contains "top-menu" in its name):

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($data);
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
  $targets = $xpath->query(".//div[contains(@class, 'top-menu')]//li/@class");
  $classNames_array = array();
  foreach ($targets as $target) {
  $classNames_array[] = $target->textContent;
  }
  print_r(array_values($classNames_array));
```

Code to return array of div class names that contains "top-menu"

```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTML($data);
   $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
   $targets = $xpath->query(".//div[contains(@class, 'top-menu')]");
   $classNames_array = array();
   foreach ($targets as $target) {
   $classNames_array[] = $target->textContent;
   }
    print_r(array_values($classNames_array));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have two XPath steps instead: one to find the divs, then for each div, one to find its corresponding list items:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$classNames = [];

foreach ($xpath->query(".//div[contains(@class, 'top-menu')]") as $div) {
    $divClass = $div->getAttribute('class');
    foreach ($xpath->query('.//li/@class', $div) as $liClass) {
        $classNames[$divClass][] = $liClass->textContent;
    }
}

print_r($classNames);
```

The second call makes use of [`DOMXPath::query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)'s second argument, `$contextNode`.

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/3gUmN)